# Cannot use Retrofit on the emulator with http://10.0.2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost, retrofit

I have recently downloaded Retrofit 1.6.1 and try to test it on simple examples.
I have noticed that it semms not to work through the emulator, using the 10.0.2.2 address.

Here is my simple Java code:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://10.0.2.2/sisecurite").build();
IssueTicketInterface issueTickets = restAdapter.create(IssueTicketInterface.class);

issueTickets.syncIssueTickets(55, new Callback<IssueTicketsCollection>() {
    @Override
    public void success(IssueTicketsCollection issueTickets, Response response) {
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError exception) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

The error Retrofit gives me is:

```
failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The error shows up directly, it does not wait for 15 seconds, as indicated in the error message. Moreover, the 10.0.2.2 seems to be transformed into 127.0.0.1

Here is the complete stack trace from the `failure()` method:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:389)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
... 7 more
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
... 23 more
```

Please note I have full access to `http://10.0.2.2/sisecurite` through the emulator's web browser, so it seems to be a Retrofit-specific error.

Has someone always has the same problem, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason of this behaviour.

It turned out that the page I tried to access **redirected me** to a login form. This is why Retrofit threw an error saying "failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1".